# Dynamically create/draw text box (Like in Paint/Photoshop) on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, textbox, html5-canvas

I had now developed a canvas which you can draw on it. How do I able to draw a text box and write text on it? Like the one in Photoshop, where we click the place where we want to write our text, a text input in created and we can write on it.

Thanks!

Comment: The simple answer is: you can't (see the dup in the dup..). To do this however, you have to implement your own solution (example in answer in dup).

Comment: Thanks for the link, guess I didn't look hard enough.